# How do I view the friend requests I've sent, by date?

Tags: facebook, friends, facebook-friend-request

Going to [this page](https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=jwl&outgoing=1) allows you to view the Facebook friend requests you've sent, but this doesn't show when each friend request was sent.

**Is there any way to find out when a friendship request was sent, and sort all my sent friendship requests by date?**

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to definitively determine the answer to this question. As *serenesat* mentions, the feature is accessed by the Activity Log, but is a lot more intuitive and a lot easier than that makes it sound, especially since the newly-designed interface was introduced.

### To browse sent friend requests by the date you sent them

1. From any Facebook page, click the settings arrow at the top right of the navigation bar, and in the menu that appears, click `Activity Log`

[image]

2. Click the `More` button under the left sidebar. In the expanded list of options, select `Added Friends` to narrow the activity displayed down to those involving only friends.

[image]

3. Click the `Sent Friend Requests` sub-option to further narrow down the activity displayed to only the friend requests you've sent.

[image]

4. You'll now be able to scroll down through the history of friend requests you've sent to people on Facebook. To get the exact date and time that a particular request was sent, simply roll the mouse over its entry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, as of now there is no such feature (officially) available which shows sent friend request date.

To know when you have sent a request to someone you have to check the Activity Log.